# How to change the colors only of all email templates in M2?

Tags: magento-2.1, email-templates

I've been trying to scratch my head through this most of the day, and I seem to be running in circles.

I know I shouldn't edit the default email templates at all (and I'm cool with that).  I've found the default templates in `Vendor > Magento > theme-frontend-luma > web > css >` source.  However, I cannot see anywhere where the colors of this theme are specified.

I don't want to change the layout of the email templates, but I just want to change the default colors (and the logo obviously).

How/Where do I create my own email template theme that doesn't interfere with the actual website theme ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

In your custom theme add `_email-variables.less` and `_email-extend.less` files. These files are located in `web/css/source/_email-extend.less` under `Luma theme`. You should copy them over and then use these files to overwrite or extend the email styles. You'll need to make sure these files are deployed/compiled correctly to see changes.

To change the email logo, in Admin Panel go to `Stores > Settings > Configuration`
under General, click on the Design. Open Email setion and click on browse to choose your logo.

Comment: yeah, the logo I've fixed. I'm just trying to set the background and foreground colors to match our website theme.  So I'm assuming I can just drop those files into the existing theme we are using?

Comment: Great about the logo and yes that should be it, that's how I modified styles of my emails

Comment: If answer was helpful please accept and upvote so it doesn't get littered and can benefit someone else ;)

Comment: I would, except that I have tried the above, and it started to cause compilation issues.  I had to revert.  I'll be tackling this again later in a few weeks, and will update this thread at that time.